# Create secret for Gcp service accont using Yaml in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am trying to create a Kubernetes secret for the IAM service account of GCP from the download file which has the following structure

**secret.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: gcp-secret
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
type: kubernetes.io/opaque
stringData:
  gcs-config: |
     {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "fetebird-350310",
      "private_key_id": "5566b5e81ce3cb9530659be6c70e07a36dcbd581",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvww2VjXHj9/7gQ8ZWs/OaQKBgQDDHqb2rG4b5wGMDeeW\nuNTofm7xfC9yAHBm4Rug6hXpYSy36LUrpe0agZqzcLpH2G4xTarQyx76sPXVCpGc\nyFAQ6Jvj1kqM2pHJlGg+L1kX1mZ96jOyyZ2mxPV3r837q90w4CqT2rLKTF9VgWre\nSD6P7h2JbJ46Xzu4Mp72wSxSCg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "ssss@ssss-350310.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "sssssssss",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/fetebird%40fetebird-350310.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

Run the below command, it does create a secret, However, the authentication is not working via the service account

```
kubectl apply --filename secret.yaml
```

**service-account.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: git-service-account
secrets:
  - name: git-ssh-auth
  - name: gcp-secret
```

**Pipeline-run**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: run-pipeline
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
spec:
  serviceAccountNames:
    - taskName: clone-repository
      serviceAccountName: git-service-account
    - taskName: build
      serviceAccountName: gcp-service-account
  pipelineRef:
    name: fetebird-discount
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-workspace
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: fetebird-discount-pvc
  params:
    - name: repo-url
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/discount.git
```

The way I am creating secret from secret.yaml is correct?

That service account has these permissions

[image]

Getting error on tekton pipeline as

[image]

If I provide public access to the artifact registry, it works. Somehow the permission are not working for me, not sure how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: git-service-account
secrets:
  - name: git-ssh-auth
  - name: pubsub-key
  - name: gcp-secret
```

You did not add the secret to the list of secrets in the serviceaccount.

Comment: I already tried that one, didn't work

Comment: Did you assign the service account to the "PipelineRun" as well?

Comment: yes, I have updated the question with pipeline run details, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following? And please try to merge all the secrets in the single service account.

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: run-pipeline
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
spec:
  serviceAccountName: git-service-account
  pipelineRef:
    name: fetebird-discount
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-workspace
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: fetebird-discount-pvc
  params:
    - name: repo-url
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/discount.git
```

There is one another suggestion i could try here. Did you include the annotation like suggested here?

https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/auth/#configuring-ssh-auth-authentication-for-git

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ssh-key
  annotations:
    tekton.dev/git-0: github.com # Described below
type: kubernetes.io/ssh-auth
stringData:
  ssh-privatekey: <private-key>
  # This is non-standard, but its use is encouraged to make this more secure.
  # If it is not provided then the git server's public key will be requested
  # when the repo is first fetched.
  known_hosts: <known-hosts>
```

Comment: I tried this already this doesn't work for me, here is the link for that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72698689/manage-multiple-service-account-for-each-task-in-pipeline-tekton-ci-cd

Comment: I think in the Tekton container, I need to have that GCP configuration JSON file and expose that file as an environment variable. Not sure how can I do this.